# How to execute timeout on a certain block of code

Tags: for-loop, try-catch, executor

I am trying with the following:

For example, I have some code block which takes more than 30 seconds to execute, but I want to stop it if it takes more than 30 seconds.

So I want to set a timeout on a certain block of code, but the loop should execute for other iterations.

This is my code so far:

```
For (i=0;i<3;i++) 
{ 
  private void gracefulShutDown(ExecutorService executor) 
  { 
    try 
    {  
      executor.shutdown(); 
      executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // some code here takes more than 30 sencons to execute 
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    { 
      log.error("Termination interrupted", e); 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
      if (!executor.isTerminated()) 
      { 
        log.warn("Killing non-finished tasks"); 
      } 
      executor.shutdownNow(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting code in the comments. Code can only in questions and answers be formatted properly.

Comment: (From Review:) I added the code from the comments and added two relevant tags. **Please add the programming language you're using as a tag.**